# Numbering a list in Word document starting after 1

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

How can I start a numbered list in Word that doesn't begin with 1? Or how can I skip a few numbers to start later?

I am editing a Word document on Mac OS, I have a numbered all the points I am making but I would like to delete points 1 to 3 but keep numbers after number 4? When I delete the first 3 numbers, number 4 defaults to number 1.

So instead of:

```
1.
2.
3.
4.
```

instead I want it to start like so:

```
4.
5.
6.
7.
```

Comment: I find it a bit hard to understand what you are saying, but I **think** you are saying that you want to set the starting number in a numbered list, and asking how to do that. Is that correct?

Comment: you should be able to select the "numbered" item (in your case 4), go to Paragraph -> Numbered List -> Define number format. You can then change the starting number of your item to whatever you'd like.

Comment: See Set Numbering Value in [How to create a list with restarting and continuing numbering](http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/how_to_create_a_list_with_restarting_and_continuing_numbering.html)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the list (i.e., the 1. item), choose **Bullets and Numbering...*, click on the **Numbered** tab (if not there already) and choose **Customize...**.

There you can enter a **Start at** value.